# Ruby getter recursively builds tree

Tags: ruby

This is a getter in a class.  It recursively generates a tree/hash to a certain level of depth.

```
def children(depth: 4, article_children: self.root.child_links)
  get_children = lambda do |depth, article_children|
    article_children.map do |uri|
      if (depth == 0)
        Article.new(uri: uri)
      else
        article = Article.new(uri: uri)
        { article => get_children.call(depth - 1, article.child_links) }
      end
    end
  end

  @children ||= get_children.call(depth, self.root.child_links)
  return @children
end
```

I would like feedback on these specific areas:

- Readability/maintainability concerns
- Is this an appropriate use of lambda?
- Style concerns
- General feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously people are going to have different opinions. I think that adding a lambda just makes it more difficult to read, I would put that in a private emethod (which also has the advantage of making it testable)

There is a bug in your code:

```
def children(depth: 4, article_children: self.root.child_links)
  @children ||= get_children.call(depth, self.root.child_links)
  return @children
end
```

You pass `self.root_child_links` to `get_children`. You should be passing `article_children`.

Some style notes:

```
def children(depth: 4, article_children: self.root.child_links)
  ...    
  @children ||= get_children.call(depth, self.root.child_links)
  return @children
end
```

The `return` is generally considered bad style. It is enough to specify just the return value on the last line. i.e. just `@children`. In this case even that is unnecessary as the assignment above returns the value of `@children`. iow I would just write:

```
def children(depth: 4, article_children: self.root.child_links)
  ...    
  @children ||= get_children.call(depth, self.root.child_links)
end
```

Also (simplifying this piece of code to show my point)

```
article_children.map do |uri|
  article = Article.new(uri: uri)
  { article => get_children.call(depth - 1, article.child_links) }
end
```

This returns an array of hashes which is an odd way to structure data, wouldn't it make sense to return a single hash.

Lastly instead of passing `article_links` into the method I would pass the `article`.

My take on this code would be something like:

```
def children(depth: 4, root: self.root)
  @children ||= recurse_children(depth, root)
end

private

def recurse_children(depth, article)
  article.child_links.reduce do |hash, uri|
    article = Article.new(uri: uri)
    hash[article] = depth > 0 ? recurse_children(article) : nil
    hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.   I'm not entirely sold on your thoughts concerning the use of lambda here, but it's definitely something I'll consider.  You are correct, returning a list of hashes is odd, and not what I intended.  Definitely something I will fix.

Comment: Some things are just personal preference. Just settle on a style and stick to it

Comment: Is a private method more in line with convention than a lambda would be?

Comment: I've never seen anything either way. My preference is methods simply because I find them more readable